# Objects must be of type PHAsset

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I use this code for delete images from photos app that is selected by image picker.
After selecting multiple images it will return the selected image in assetArray.
Now i want to delete those images,But it will give error "Object must be of type PHAsset"

```
 - (void)assetsPickerController:(GMImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)assetArray
     {
      [picker.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
NSLog(@"===%@===",assetArray);
void (^completionHandler)(BOOL, NSError *) = ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
};

   // Delete asset from library
      [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
      [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[assetArray]];
} completionHandler:completionHandler];

  NSLog(@"GMImagePicker: User ended picking assets. Number of selected items is: %lu", (unsigned long)assetArray.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an array of array.Just do like this:

```
[PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetArray];
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i get original image from PHAsset. Reason is i want to store selected images in document directory.